# Can we please be added to the sites allowed to embed Youtube videos?

Tags: feature-request

I don't know if Jeff's list has changed at all since [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/284336) was written but... as a site where videos could do a lot to help with technique, I think it would be really useful to have YouTube video embedding turned on here.

I do understand that it's relatively rare... if Jeff's list is correct, only four sites in the network allow it... But I think we have a good need for it.

If this request gets massively downvoted, that clearly means that I'm the only one who wants this feature, which is totally fine... but I thought I'd throw it at the wall and see what sticks.

Comment: Yes pleeeeeeaaaaase

Comment: How many questions are we going to have about `youtube-embedding`?

Comment: @Matt you mean for the tag? Who knows... but it's a valid meta topic. I don't like questions with only the required tags and I didn't know what else to use.

Comment: Only four sites in the network? Wow ...

Comment: It [took months](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/2210/revisions) for this to be implemented on SFF, even though it was a graduated site. We might have a long wait here ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sure... but M&TV had it before they left Beta, so... maybe it was you all who paved the way for M&TV and the other sites? .... Wait... does Anime seriously not have embedding?

Answer (score 1):

## I think it is a good idea.

Even if we don't have a large need for it the overhead for rendering the links is minimal. Not like MathJax or something of the same. In case we don't get this added I wanted to reference a [Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263626/266361) that shows a simple way to get *almost* the same thing with markdown:

> ```
> [![Video thumbnail](https://img.youtube.com/vi/gUmMcecHN9s/mqdefault.jpg)  
> **SAML101** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUmMcecHN9s)
> ```
>
> Simply replace gUmMcecHN9s (in both places) with the video ID of your choice and alter the caption.